# How do I glaze vegetables?

Tags: vegetables

I'm looking to glaze some carrots, maybe some beets, and a decent chunk of the rest of the season's worth of farmshare. I'm sure there's plenty of recipes on the internet, but I'm looking for some general advice as to method: how to do it properly, what to look out for, etc. Help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trim your carrots, rutabaga, turnips, etc. to consistent sizes and put in a large saute pan.  Add stock or water (amount will depend on vegetables and their density along with quantitye of vegetables.  Start with enough to come about 2/3 up the volume of veg.) along with some salt, a couple tablespoons of butter and a couple tablespoons of sugar.

Bring the liquid to a simmer and cover lightly with a lid or a circle of parchment paper.  Simmer until vegetables are getting tender.  Remove the lid and continue to simmer until liquid evaporates and sugar and butter create a nice glaze.  Watch at the end to make sure the sugar doesn't burn.  Add any desired herbs, taste and adjust seasoning and serve.

Comment: Huh. Totally different method than I'm used to (as outlined below): cook veg, toss to glaze, serve. You cook the sugar/etc right into them. I may need to try that.

Answer (score 3):

Cook your veg to desired doneness. Toss in a pan with a slightly reduced mix of water, sugar (not tons) or honey, salt (pinch), any spices or herbs you care to add. Serve. It's really that simple.

Watch that you don't cook your water/sugar down too far or it will caramelize. You probably want in the neighbourhood of 2tbsp sugar/4-5tbsp water. Use less water if using honey.

For spicing.. cumin is aces with carrots, star anise with beets. I'd use honey for beets, more rounded flavour to complement the earthy notes.